# Concurrency Fairness & Deadlock

Tags: concurrency

Can somebody give appropriate definitions for the terms Fairness and Deadlock. I am informed that these terms are used in concurrent processes.

Comment: You're better off at wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_nondeterminism#Fairness

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, concurrent processes share CPU, the operating system schedules CPU bursts for each process to run. Fairness is one of the things needs to be considered in order to achieve progress, and also to prevent starvation.

Deadlock is a situation when there is a circle of dependency, where each process waits for another process to progress. you will need to read also about Mutex and critical section.

Comment: plus 1 for "in a nutshell"